# Why is my dynamic src path not working unless I append an empty string to the end of it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js and tried to create a dynamic src using an object's properties like this:

```
<img :src='"../assets/" + project.image.name + "." + project.image.extension'>
```

But it doesn't work and I don't get any errors in the console. Interestingly, when I try this:

```
<img :src='"../assets/" + project.image.name + "." + project.image.extension + ""'>
```

It works just fine. I'm not doing anything else than appending an empty string to the end of it. Even though it works fine, it irks me that I don't understand why.

Comment: Weird.  Can you look at network requests to determine if there's a difference between the two?

Comment: Have you tried this: `<img :src="'../assets/' + project.image.name + '.' + project.image.extension">`?

Comment: Try with template syntax (with backticks: ` ): `<img :src="\`../assets/${project.image.name}.${project.image.extension}\`">`.

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work", what do you mean by that exactly? What happens? What is the resulting `src`? Is there a build error?

Comment: @DecadeMoon I see the alt of the image instead of the actual image and the icon which shows when an image is not found. Also on the network tab the first request ( which one doesn't work ) leads to http://localhost:8080/assets/art.jpg whereas the second request which works leads to http://localhost:8080/img/art.6d3734e2.jpg . Maybe it is a webpack related issue?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually even the second shouldn't work.

Proper way is

```
computed: {
  src() {
    return require("./assets/" + this.image.name + "." + this.image.extension);
  }
},
// <img :src="src">
```